# Relation between $(km)!$ and few others

Tags: number-theory, factorial

Show that $(m!)^k, (k!)^m, k!m!$ are all less equal $(km)!$ where $k$ and $m$ are integers greater than $1$.

I tried it by inducting on $k$ keeping $m$ fixed but got stuck at inductive step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $0\leq j\leq k-1$,
$$
\prod_{t=1}^m (jm+t)\geq \prod_{t=1}^m t=m!
$$

So
$$
(km)!=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\prod_{t=1}^m(jm+t)\geq \prod_{j=0}^{k-1} m!=(m!)^k
$$

Switching the roles of $k$ and $m$ yields $(km)!\geq (k!)^m$.

For the last one, assume $k\leq m$ without loss of generality. If $k\geq 2$ then
$$
(km)!\geq (m!)^k\geq m!m!\geq k!m!.
$$
If $k=1$ then $(km)!=m!=k!m!$.

Added later: The first one can be done with a combinatorics argument instead. $(km)!$ is the number of ways of ordering $km$ objects. Split those $km$ objects into $k$ groups of $m$ each. Then the total number of orderings is at least the number of ways of ordering each of the $k$ groups of $m$ individually. The latter figure is $(m!)^k$ since each group has $m!$ orderings and there are $k$ groups.

Comment: is there a way to argue whole thing combinatorially

Comment: I wrote already how to see $(km)!\geq (m!)^k$ with orderings. The symmetric argument works for $(km)!\geq (k!)^m$. A slight tweaking works for $(km)!\geq k!m!$. Instead of choosing different orderings for the $k$ groups of $m$ (which amounts to $(m!)^k$), choose one of $m!$ orderings and use it on all $k$ groups, but then change the order of the $k$ groups in $k!$ ways.